# Server 2016/Win7 - create new user with content of existing profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2016

I am having problems with connecting a domain member computer to a new Server 2016 (computer account).

.....

**EDIT :** basically 2 errors come up:

1. *"This computer has been registered under a different Name before. Please change the computer name or remove the problematic computer account"*
2. *"The computer is already connected to a different Windows Server Network"*

.......

Have tried several approaches (leaving & re-entering the domain, changing the computername, deleting the computer account from the domain [which then reappears after a while]) but nothing has worked thus far.

Now, as a last resort I'm afraid I have to reinstall the Client Computers OS (Win7) and doing so will loose the local user profiles (which are not stored on the server AND on the C: drive of the Computer). Is there any smooth way to rebuild the entire User Profile after client computers OS is re-installed?

as a backup I am copying the profile with a robocopy command to a temporary folder on the server and hoe to being able to re-use this as is later on. I am aware that as soon I login with the existing user to the new installed computer a new Profile folder will be created on that machine. So is there any way to re-create the existing files in there besides manually choosing whatever seems to be of importance?

Comment: `I am having problems with connecting a domain member computer to a new Server 2016 (computer account). Have tried several approaches (leaving & re-entering the domain, changing the computername) but nothing has worked thus far.` - Maybe tell us more about that and we can help solve the actual problem.

Comment: please see edit above @joeqwerty. Honestly I am beyond trying to solve that problem as I have gone through many circles with that thus far already. But would be open to try if there is an obvious solution I just haven't been trying yet. None then the ones mentioned popped up before though.